# Pandas - get rolling max of last n items of higher frequency (with respect of unclosed fixed time)

Tags: pandas

I have the data:

```py
index = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-01 08:00:00', '2000-01-01 08:00:01',
               '2000-01-01 08:00:03', '2000-01-01 08:00:04',
               '2000-01-01 08:00:05', '2000-01-01 08:00:06',
               '2000-01-01 08:00:09', '2000-01-01 08:00:10',
               '2000-01-01 08:00:11', '2000-01-01 08:00:12',
               '2000-01-01 08:00:15', '2000-01-01 08:00:16',
               '2000-01-01 08:00:18', '2000-01-01 08:00:19',
               '2000-01-01 08:00:20', '2000-01-01 08:00:22',
               '2000-01-01 08:00:23', '2000-01-01 08:00:24',
               '2000-01-01 08:00:25', '2000-01-01 08:00:26',
               '2000-01-01 08:00:27', '2000-01-01 08:00:28'])
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [4,3,8,15,2,3,14,17,15,20,13,2,5,15,10,10,13,20,1,3,10,11]},
                    index=index)
df
```

I found that I can get the `max` for the particular time interval by:

```py
df2 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5s', base=2)).rolling('5s', min_periods=1).max()
df2
```

**I'd like to get the rolling max value of last 2 groups of 5s time interval for each record with respect of uncompleted fixed actual time interval.**

I found that rolling max of the two fixed 5s intervals can be obtained by:

```py
df3 = df.resample('5s', base=2).max().rolling(2).max()
```

But for example in record `2000-01-01 08:00:22` should be result `15` insted of `20`. I cannot find how to combine this two approach..

**Result should be**:

```
                                          A  last-2x-5s-intervals-max
2000-01-01 07:59:57 2000-01-01 08:00:00   4                       NaN (not enough data)
                    2000-01-01 08:00:01   3                       NaN (not enough data)
2000-01-01 08:00:02 2000-01-01 08:00:03   8                       8.0 (max from previous 5s to actual record/to actual unfinished 5s time interval)
                    2000-01-01 08:00:04  15                      15.0 (max from 2000-01-01 07:59:57 to 2000-01-01 08:00:04)
                    2000-01-01 08:00:05   2                      15.0 (max from 2000-01-01 07:59:57 to 2000-01-01 08:00:05)
                    2000-01-01 08:00:06   3                      15.0 (max from 2000-01-01 07:59:57 to 2000-01-01 08:00:06)
2000-01-01 08:00:07 2000-01-01 08:00:09  14                      15.0 (max from 2000-01-01 08:00:02 to 2000-01-01 08:00:09)
                    2000-01-01 08:00:10  17                      17.0 (max from 2000-01-01 08:00:02 to 2000-01-01 08:00:10)
                    2000-01-01 08:00:11  15                      17.0 (max from 2000-01-01 08:00:02 to 2000-01-01 08:00:11)
2000-01-01 08:00:12 2000-01-01 08:00:12  20                      20.0 (max from 2000-01-01 08:00:07 to 2000-01-01 08:00:12)
                    2000-01-01 08:00:15  13                      20.0 (etc...)
                    2000-01-01 08:00:16   2                      20.0
2000-01-01 08:00:17 2000-01-01 08:00:18   5                      20.0
                    2000-01-01 08:00:19  15                      20.0
                    2000-01-01 08:00:20  10                      20.0
2000-01-01 08:00:22 2000-01-01 08:00:22  10                      15.0
                    2000-01-01 08:00:23  13                      15.0
                    2000-01-01 08:00:24  20                      20.0
                    2000-01-01 08:00:25   1                      20.0
                    2000-01-01 08:00:26   3                      20.0
2000-01-01 08:00:27 2000-01-01 08:00:27  10                      20.0
                    2000-01-01 08:00:28  11                      20.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reasearch, and help from @Ben.T, this is the state I wanted to achieve. Choosable higher timeframe frequency and period:

```
HIGHER_TF_FREQ = '5s'
HIGHER_TF_PERIOD = 4
df2gr = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=HIGHER_TF_FREQ, base=2))
df2 = df2gr.rolling(HIGHER_TF_FREQ, min_periods=1).max().dropna()
df2['last_2x'] = df2.assign(l=df2gr.max().dropna().rolling(HIGHER_TF_PERIOD-1).max().shift().loc[df2.index.get_level_values(0)].to_numpy()).max(axis=1, skipna=False)
df2
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to get the `cummax` per group on the first level of index in `df2` to get the current maximum in the group, `assign` the `max` per group of first level of index once `shift` to get the max of the previous group, then reindex using `loc` with the first level of index of df2 for getting the right value at the right row, and the `max` over the columns:

```
df2gr = df2.groupby(level=0)
df2['last_2x'] = df2gr.cummax()\
                      .assign(l=df2gr.max().shift()
                                     .loc[df2.index.get_level_values(0)]
                                     .to_numpy())\
                      .max(axis=1, skipna=False)

print (df2)
                                            A  last_2x
2000-01-01 07:59:57 2000-01-01 08:00:00   4.0      NaN
                    2000-01-01 08:00:01   4.0      NaN
2000-01-01 08:00:02 2000-01-01 08:00:03   8.0      8.0
                    2000-01-01 08:00:04  15.0     15.0
                    2000-01-01 08:00:05  15.0     15.0
                    2000-01-01 08:00:06  15.0     15.0
2000-01-01 08:00:07 2000-01-01 08:00:09  14.0     15.0
                    2000-01-01 08:00:10  17.0     17.0
                    2000-01-01 08:00:11  17.0     17.0
2000-01-01 08:00:12 2000-01-01 08:00:12  20.0     20.0
                    2000-01-01 08:00:15  20.0     20.0
                    2000-01-01 08:00:16  20.0     20.0
2000-01-01 08:00:17 2000-01-01 08:00:18   5.0     20.0
                    2000-01-01 08:00:19  15.0     20.0
                    2000-01-01 08:00:20  15.0     20.0
2000-01-01 08:00:22 2000-01-01 08:00:22  10.0     15.0
                    2000-01-01 08:00:23  13.0     15.0
                    2000-01-01 08:00:24  20.0     20.0
                    2000-01-01 08:00:25  20.0     20.0
                    2000-01-01 08:00:26  20.0     20.0
2000-01-01 08:00:27 2000-01-01 08:00:27  10.0     20.0
                    2000-01-01 08:00:28  11.0     20.0
```

Comment: Wow, excellent result, thank you very much!
There is some magic for me, could you explain the particular steps?

Comment: `df2= df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5s', base=2)).rolling('5s', min_periods=1).max()` **and** 
`df2gr = df2.groupby(level=0); df3=df2gr.cummax()`, **there df2 and df3 have the same output, or not? Can be used without cumsum:** `df2['last_2x'] = df2.assign(l=df2gr.max().shift().loc[df2.index.get_level_values(0)].to_numpy()).max(axis=1, skipna=False)`

Comment: @Jan yes you are right `df2` and `df3` how you define them are the same so it is not necessary to use `cummax`, I guess I got a bit mixed up between `df` and `df2` in my answer, good point :)

Comment: I tried to use `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5s', base=2)).cummax().assign(l=dfgr.max().shift().loc[df.index.get_level_values(0)].to_numpy()).max(axis=1, skipna=False)` **, but I don't have grouped index**  `df.index.get_level_values(0)`

Comment: @Jan you need to create `df2` with what I wrote, but do you need df2 at some point?

Comment: Next goal is to calculate rolling higher timeframe minimum of another column (not included in this simple example) for every record. My finish purpose is to calculate my own "indicator" function for every row (some pivot value) based on these high and low from higher timeframe.

Comment: I mean `df2` index(0) won't use in the future computation. Only this one.

Comment: @Jan I guess without going through df2 like: `dfgr = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5s', base=2))` and then `df['last_2x'] = dfgr[['A']].cummax().assign(l=dfgr['A'].max().shift().reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq='s')).ffill()).max(axis=1, skipna=False)`

Comment: Thank you, @Ben, its great. I suppose if I'd like to get 3 `5s` interval, I add the shift parametr to `... .max().shift(2).reindex( ...`.

Comment: @Jan shift(2) will only give you the value 2 interval ago, if you want the previous one and the 2 previous ago, you need to create 2 columns in assign

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211151/discussion-between-jan-and-ben-t).